# How can I apply DragFlickBehavior in code?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

How can I apply the win8nl DragFlickBehavior for a grid in code behind?

Any help will really appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution

```
       Win8nl.Behaviors.DragFlickBehavior behaviour = new DragFlickBehavior();
        WinRtBehaviors.Interaction.GetBehaviors(grdNew).Add(behaviour);
```

Answer (score 0):

Behaviours are currently not supported on Win8Dev. Have a look at 
http://winrtbehaviors.codeplex.com/

This post by the author shows how to use implement it
http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/attached-behaviors-for-windows-8-metro.html

Comment: Right and win8nl uses those.

Comment: see I spend more time of twitter :( read Win8nl as a #win8nl and assumed it was associated with author ) and not a lib by the same